# Create a Jar from within a Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to create a `jar` file from some class and `txt` files that are located inside a `jar`. It is a simple server program which generate a client.

The folder I want to access is indeed in my `jar` file if I inspect it with WinRAR. I have made a method that works in my `IDE (Eclipse)`. If I run my program in the IDE I am able to generate a jar which executes.

I understand I can not access the files inside my jar files as files. However my method uses the path to the file.

This method creates a manifest files without any problem:

```
public void createClientJar(String path, String fileName, String hostAddress, String portNumber, String connectionInterval) {
    try {
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MANIFEST_VERSION, "1.0");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.CLASS_PATH, ".");
        manifest.getMainAttributes().put(Attributes.Name.MAIN_CLASS, "client.utils.Client");

        JarOutputStream target = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + fileName + ".jar"), manifest);

        File serverRoot = new File(getClass().getResource("/client").getPath());

        addSourceToJar(serverRoot, target, "", hostAddress, portNumber, connectionInterval);

        target.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method to generate the jar file:

```
private void addSourceToJar(File source, JarOutputStream target, String folder, String hostAddress, String portNumber, String connectionInterval) {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    File entryFile = null;
    JarEntry entry = null;
    String path = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
    String previousFolder = folder;

    try {
        if (source.isDirectory()) {
            if (!path.isEmpty()) {
                if (!path.endsWith("/"))
                    path += "/";

                if (!path.endsWith("bin/")) {
                    entryFile = new File(path);
                    entry = new JarEntry(previousFolder + entryFile.getName() + "/");
                    previousFolder += entryFile.getName() + "/";

                    target.putNextEntry(entry);
                    target.closeEntry();
                }
            }
            for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles()) {
                addSourceToJar(nestedFile, target, previousFolder, hostAddress, portNumber, connectionInterval);
            }
            return;
        }

        entryFile = new File(path);
        entry = new JarEntry(previousFolder + entryFile.getName());
        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
        target.putNextEntry(entry);

        if(entry.getName().contains("data")){
            // Replaces connection data in data.txt
            replaceData(path, hostAddress, portNumber, connectionInterval);
        }

        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            target.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        target.closeEntry();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is I get an `Nullpointer` Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at model.Model.createClientJar(Model.java:204)
```

Which is this line:

```
File serverRoot = new File(getClass().getResource("/client").getPath());
```

Besides I think this is not the way to go. As I am not able to acces the files in my Jar directly.

I can not come up with the logic to alter my method so it works both in my IDE and when exported as a `Runnable Jar` .

I would like someone to point me in the right direction on what lines are going to fail inside my `addSourceToJar()` method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to do? Modify the nested jar while it is inside the original outer jar?

Comment: Why dont you simply add the client-jar at build time?

Comment: The structure of my project can be seen here : [link](http://s16.postimg.org/m50amber9/Naamloos.png)

Comment: I'm trying to generate a executable jar which require some user input. The user should be able to create a jar multiple times.

There is no jar inside my project. It are just java/text/class files. I hope you understand.

Comment: I had similar problems with `getResource` and eventually changed to `getResourceAsStream` which worked. Second question is what you want to achieve, why do you need to create multiple clients. Can't everybody use the same client?

Comment: But I do not want the stream I need the entire file? No I need to make it so it is possible to generate multiple clients.

Comment: I managed to get it done using the getResourceAsStream.. Thanks